# vibrating circular membrane that doesn't satisfy wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

I'm studying a "vibrating circular membrane" problem and I've attached some screenshots of one possible mode of vibration.

[image]

[image]

The equation for this mode of vibration is $$ \varphi(t,x,y)=\big(3\sin^2(t)x^2+3\cos^2(t)y^2\big)e^{\frac{1}{\log(x^2+y^2)}} $$

for time, $t\in(0,\infty)$ and $x,y\in(-1,1).$ Also $\varphi=0$ on $\partial\Omega.$

However I checked that $\varphi(t,x,y)$ does not satisfy the partial differential equation:

$$ \frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial t^2}=c^2\bigg( \frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial y^2} \bigg) $$

> So I'm just wondering if $\varphi$ is a solution to a partial differential equation? I'm not sure how to reverse construct the differential equation that $\varphi$ satisfies.

I'd like to characterize the normal modes of this system but if the wave equation isn't satisfied I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: If it doesn't satisfy the wave equation, then what makes you think that it's a valid vibrational mode? In other words, where did you come across this mode and its equation?

Comment: If it doesn't satisfy the wave equation then why couldn't it be a valid vibrational mode?

Comment: Where did you come across this question? If the author called it a "vibrational mode", then presumably they say what they mean by a "vibrational mode". In most situations, that phrase refers to the solution to a partial differential equation and likely to the wave equation

Comment: @BenGrossmann it doesn't satisfy the wave equation so it's not a valid question (I should have realized this)